# unable to give time duration to addclass()

Tags: jquery

I am Using jQuery addclass and removeclass methods for adding and removing the class, butI want to give the time duration for added class, I have written following code,
 I have added googleapi

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and the jquery file is

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#frmlogin').validate({
rules:{
    username:{required:true},
    password:{required:true}
},
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('text-success').addClass('has-warning');
},
success: function(element) {
    element
    .text('OK!').addClass('login-valid')
    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-warning').addClass('text-success',500);

},
submitHandler: function(form)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "login_process.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType:'json',
        contenType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: $("#frmlogin").serialize(),
        success:function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
            if(response.ok==1)
            {
                $(location).attr('href','blog.php');
            }
            else{
                $('#msg-login-error').html('Wrong Username & Password !');
            }
        }

     });

  }
 });


});
```

I Have used

```
.closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-warning').addClass('text-success',500);
```

Kindly give me the solution.

Comment: you seem to be adding an extra parameter to addClass() that isn't accepted, see [addClass documentation](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `setTimeout(function,milliseconds)`

```
element = element.text('OK!').addClass('login-valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-warning');
setTimeout(function() { element.addClass('text-success'); },500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
.closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-warning').delay(500).queue(function(next){

     $(this).addClass("text-success")

     next();
});
```